# MPI programming to implement large data gathering from many workers

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing

Now, I have a application that composed of single master and many workers. The application requirement is very simple: workers finish some jobs and send data to master and master store these data into files separately. I can simply use MPI_Send on worker side to send data to master. But master does not know the data sending sequence. Some workers go fast while some are slow. More specifically, suppose there are 5 workers, then the data sending sequence may be 1,3,4,5,2 or 2,5,4,1,3. If I just write a for loop like for(i=1 to 5) on master side with MPI_Recv to get data, the master and some faster worker have to wait for a long time. I know MPI_Gather can implement this. But I am not sure is MPI_Gather works parallelly or just some  sequential calls of MPI_Recv? Another issue is my data is extremely large, more than 1GB data needed to be sent to master. If I divide the data into trunks, it may make it more complex. I do not think MPI_Gather can work. I also tried to think about raw socket programming, but I do not think it is a good practice. Would you give me some suggestion please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to receive the data back at the master, but since each task takes a different amount of time to finish, you don't want to loop over all the processors in order so that the receive for process 5 (if it's finished) isn't waiting for the receive from process 3 (which is still running).

If want to receive out-of-order, it's possible to use `mpi_recv` with the `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` constant as the rank of the processor sending the message.  You should then be able to inspect the returned status to determine which processor sent the message to send more work.  Rather than looping over all processors, just have a single receive statement in your work loop.

Comment: +1 for `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`, that's the easiest solution. Alternatively, you could use five asynchronous receives (`MPI_Irecv`) on the master end and occasionally poll them to see if they completed, but really, stick with `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`.

Comment: You're right - another issue I would have with the asynchronous receives is that it obscures your intent.  All you really care about is getting a message from *somewhere* and `mpi_any_source` underscores that.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer. I have struggled in using MPI_Waitany for a few days. Now, I think using MPI_Recv with MPI_ANY_SOURCE is pretty simple too.

Answer (score 0):

could the workers write out the files instead of sending the data back to the master?  when a worker finishes, it could send a "i'm done" message to the master.  the master, in turn could send the next chunk of work to that worker.  when there is no work left to hand out, have the master send a "no more work" message to the worker, who could then call MPI Finalize.